# Using php to open a url ending in .rss

Tags: php, xml, curl, rss, simplexml

I'm trying to load the data stored at
https://www.nextbigsound.com/charts/social50.rss using php.

I've tried using a curl and the simplexml_load_file function but neither of these are working for me. I'm pretty new to the language but the data that is displayed when I follow this link looks like nothing more than an xml document. However whenever I try to load the url, I get an error saying that it failed to load. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:
This is the line I tried with the simplexml_load_file

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file('https://www.nextbigsound.com/charts/social50.xml');
```

When I tried the curl method I used this:

```
$url = 'https://www.nextbigsound.com/charts/social50.xml';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$rss = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

To check if results were returned I just ran a simple `var_dump($rss)` but it always showed up as a boolean set to false.

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-read-an-rss-feed-with-php-screencast/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `file_get_contents` will work

```
$content = file_get_contents('https://www.nextbigsound.com/charts/social50.rss');
echo $content;
```

or with use of `simple_xml_load_string`

```
$data = file_get_contents('https://www.nextbigsound.com/charts/social50.rss');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
```

The above code assumes that there is a `https` wrapper, you can check it by this:

```
echo 'https wrapper: ', in_array(stream_get_wrappers(), $w) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
```

if is output `false` you need to alow `php_openssl` extension. This can be done by uncomenting line in your `php.ini`

```
extension=php_openssl.dll // on windows machine
extension=php_openssl.so // on unix machine
```

Comment: When I run this code I get a warning like this: "Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?" I also still receive false as the result from file_get_contents. Are there any parts of the url that should be omitted?

Comment: Where you are runnig this script? On your local devel machine or some hosting?

Comment: On a local devel machine. I've tried using other urls for this and can get those to work. Is there any way this particular feed could have a setting preventing other machines from accessing it?

Comment: Definitely it is because of secure `http` - `https`, look at my edit above.

Comment: Disabling access to rss seems to be contrary to the very idea of publishing a rss.